# zk with struts 1

Tags: zk

i am using ZK with struts 1. 
  1.i have four files, two zul file one for input and second for success message with input values
  2.Action class to get the form values , print in the server and forward to success zul file

```
when i submit the input zul page , the control is correctly going to the action class, there printed the form values correctly .From i am forwarding to another zul. there i cant get the form value
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is how to retrieve the value of the action class in a ZUL file. I think you can implement a variable resolver it and then declare the resolver in the zul file as follows.

Then, in the ZUL file, you can access them directly with EL, such as ${whatever.you.want}.

Hope it helps.